# Adding a 2010 .wsp file to SharePoint Online

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online, office-365, solution-package

Must one know and use code to upload and activate a 2010 SP .wsp file to SharePoint Online? I have a local server housed SP site I created at another location that I'd like to move to my Office365 account. I have created the .wsp file (titled Test.wsp). However, when I upload and try to activate the .wsp file I get

> "Sorry, something went wrong This site template doesn't work with the
>   current version of SharePoint."

Comment: Does this solution contain any managed code (i.e. C# or VB)?

Comment: No. I don't know code. Everything I've created in the SP 2010 site is 'plug and play', right out of SP 2010.

Comment: Did you create the WSP using Visual Studio?

Comment: Had a SharePoint developer make the .wsp for me. Not sure what was used to create the template.

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of the Office 365 SharePoint Online sandboxed solution has been deprecated as mentioned at [Removing Code-Based Sandbox Solutions in SharePoint Online.](https://dev.office.com/blogs/removing-code-based-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint-online)

So In this case, your WSP file will not work with SharePoint Online, you Should try to convert the WSP solution to [SharePoint Add-In](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930.aspx) that has the following features:

- Add-ins can be developed on both SharePoint Online and in On-Premise offerings.
- Add-ins don't have custom code that runs on the SharePoint servers.
  Almost all major types of SharePoint components can be part of a SharePoint Add-in, including pages, lists, workflows, custom content types, list templates, Web Parts, and more.
- There are two basic kinds of SharePoint Add-ins —

  - SharePoint-hosted and
  - provider-hosted.
- Add-in can be published to Microsoft’s public SharePoint store or hosted in a private store.
- Provide you with the simplest marketing and sales system based on a Microsoft online add-in store.
- Maximize your flexibility in developing future upgrades.
- Maximize your ability to take advantage of your existing non-SharePoint programming skills.

For more details check

- [SharePoint Add-In Documentatioon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930.aspx)
- [how to add a solution(.wsp) to a site on office 365 SharePoint online using PowerShell.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_dep365/how-to-add-a-solutionwsp-to-a-site-on-office-365/fed11da1-e486-4678-bd1d-cd69a902d45c)